# can't replace \n in php with content from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, str-replace

I try to avoid asking stupid questions, but this for some reason is just not working. I'm retrieving some text from a database, with newlines included. When using echo straight away, this is the output:

```
=== BOLD TEXT ===\nHere is some text.
```

This is how i retrieved it:

```
$row = $query->row();
$content=$row->course_content;
```

Neither of the following have any effect.....

```
$content= str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $content); 
$content= str_replace("\n", " ", $content);
$content = nl2br($content);
```

HOWEVER, when i hard code it in a string to the original statement,

```
$content="=== BOLD TEXT ===\nHere is some text.";
```

pang! it works... any ideas as to why it refuses to accept the database input, but is fine with the manual string?

Complete Code:

```
//Switch between these two:
$row = $query->row();
$content=$row->course_content;
$content="=== BOLD TEXT ===\nHere is some text.";
$content = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $content); 
$content = str_replace("\n", " ", $content);
$content = nl2br($content);     
echo $content;
```

Comment: What is the variable type of `course_content` in your database?

Comment: It's a longtext with utf8_general_ci

Could that be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to plain old String and seeing what happens? Because PHP is loosely typed, it's sometimes hard to keep track of the types that are moving around the code.

Comment: no, there was no result from changing it to a normal text :(

Comment: If you get `\n` in your echo output, then you've probably got literal "\" and `n` in your text, NOT a newline. Try "\\n" as your replace chars instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$row = $query->row();
$content=$row->course_content;
echo $content;
```

Do you actually see the `\n` printed to the output? Or does it actually print a new line character?

If it's the former, then you have an escaped newline in your database string instead of an actual newline character. In other words, your database string contains two characters `\` and `n`, which does not a newline make.

Try this replacement instead (or in addition to, to be completely safe):

```
$content = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\r', '\n'), "<br />", $content);
```

The [single quotes syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for the string causes php to not turn the two characters `\` and `n` into a newline character, thus it should actually match what's in your database. (You could also use `\\n`, where the first slash escapes the second slash, preventing it from turning into a newline.)

**Edit:** To answer your question, assuming you meant [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), then yes, this was expected behavior. From the documentation:

> **mysql_real_escape_string()** calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: **\x00**, **\n**, **\r**, **\ , '**, **"** and **\x1a**.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But is it 'normal', or have i done something fishy in the database? i used real_escape_string before i inserted it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$content="=== BOLD TEXT ===\nHere is some text.";
```

If you want to replace the `\n`, you should search for it using single quotes - `'\n'` (instead of `"\n"`) - the two have very different meanings in PHP.

Comment: yes! That solved it. But why didn't nl2br($content) do anything?

Comment: @Manfred, `nl2br` looks for new line characters. You don't seem to have new line characters in your string.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But is it 'normal' this way, or have i done something fishy in the database? i used real_escape_string before i inserted it.

Comment: @Manfred, Yes, maybe you called `real_escape_string` twice for the same string.

Comment: @Manfred, you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171711/double-mysql-real-escape-string-insert-of-new-line-characters-how-to-get-new-li